# Get all rows before a specific day

Tags: mysql, sql

We are using the below updated SQL to get customers list from our db whom we send SMS before 3 days.

```
SELECT * FROM sms WHERE sent_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
```

The table `sms` is updated daily along with the `sent_time` column with default value of 0 or the last sent time.

There are rows with the value of `sent_time = 0` but no row is fetched by the above script.

What is the correct SQL?

Earlier we were using the SQL with php like mentioned below:

```
$vTime = time() - ( 60*60*24*3 );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sms WHERE $vTime <= sent_time";
```

Comment: You are selecting values higher than 0, it is certain that you will never get sent_time 0... Add "OR sent_time=0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `NOW()` will return current date and time, but as I can see you have used PHP [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) before, which returns a Unix-Timestamp. The SQL equivalent is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Syntax `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

```
SELECT * FROM sms WHERE sent_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60*60*24*3);
```

Syntax `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`

```
SELECT * FROM sms WHERE sent_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) OR sent_time = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY;` returns a DATETIME while `echo time() - ( 60*60*24*3 );` returns a timestamp.

If your database column is a timestamp, your MySQL test will never work, use this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM sms WHERE sent_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change select query..

```
SELECT * FROM sms WHERE sent_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT * FROM sms WHERE sent_time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) OR sent_time=0;
```